# How to multi-line the import functions in {} in VIM?

Tags: vim

Sorry for the bad title but

With this code,,,

```
import { amethod, methodb, methodc } from '../../utils/mockData';
```

how do you make this

```
import {
  amethod,
  methodb,
  methodc
} from '../../utils/mockData';
```

with VIM? I mean how can I do it fast?

What I do is to

1. go to the first method.
2. press Enter
3. go to the end of the method..
4. press Enter...
5. go to the second method.
   6....
   ...

It's so slow with VIM. Can we do this fast in VIM? I think I can this much faster with my mouse :(

```
import { amethod, methodb, methodc } from '../...';
         ^
```

Comment: Use formatting plugins and set the formatting style? For example, [neoformat](https://github.com/sbdchd/neoformat), does not that work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f ;r<CR>;.;.;.
```

doesn't strike me as particularly slow. A tad too repetitive, maybe?

Here is a slightly smarter (but probably not *that* smart) approach:

```
ciB               " change in brackets
<CR><CR>          " insert two carriage returns
<Up>              " move up one line
<C-r>"            " insert previous content of brackets
<Esc>             " leave insert mode
:s/,/,\r/g<CR>    " put each symbol on its own line
=iB               " re-indent the content of brackets
```

that can be mapped for convenience:

```
nnoremap <key> ciB<CR><CR><Up><C-r>"<Esc>:s/,/,\r/g<CR>=iB
```

Or you can look for a proper plugin that handles corner cases gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

@romainl had a good answer, but you can also use replace for this particular case:

```
:%s/\([,{]\)/\1\n/g
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got this

```
import {
    amethod,
    methodb,
    methodc
    } from '../../utils/mockData';
```

Using this:

```
:%s/\v\{\zs( \w+,?)+ \ze}/\=substitute(submatch(0), " ", "\n\t", "g")


\v ............ very magic regex (avoid many backslashes)
{  ............ literal {
\zs ........... vim trick that marks the start of the pattern
(  ............ start of regex group 1
<Space> ....... literal space inside group 1
\w+ ........... one word or more
,?  ........... optional coma
+  ............ quantifier for the group (at least one)
<Space>
\ze ........... end of our vim search
```

The substitute function has three parts like a normal vim substitution and the submatch(0) corresponds to our regex, hence we are substituting in our regex one space for one line breake and two tabs.

Answer (score 1):

With the cursor on line1 and col1, you can press this in normal mode:

```
f 4@=';r^M'
```

then press ENTER.

Note: for the `^M` you press `Ctrl-v` then `Enter`